# CDC and replica using AWS DMS from oracle PeopleSoft to RDS postgreSQL

Tags: oracle, postgresql, amazon-rds, cdc, aws-dms

Can I do full load and CDC from oracle PeopleSoft to Amazon RDS postgreSQL using AWS DMS ?

Answer (score 0):

No, PeopleSoft database is not supported by AWS DMS.

Comment: The underlying DB is Oracle. Even if then I can do DMS ?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this document](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E80738_01/pt854pbh2/eng/pt/tgst/task_PeopleSoftDatabase-827f35.html#topofpage), PeopleSoft is not a database but an abstraction layer on top of another DB product.

So the question is: what underlying DB are you using for PeopleSoft?

After determining your source DB, look at [this document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Introduction.Sources.html#CHAP_Introduction.Sources.title) to see if it's supported by DMS.

Are you planning on using the target PostgreSQL for PeopleSoft? Make sure that t's a supported combination.

Comment: The underlying DB is Oracle. If that's the case, I believe I can do from oracle DB to postgreSQL using DMS. I have no clue about this